# Node.js, AWS Cognito - Login on front end, user verification in back end

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I have an application who consist of a frontend Angular and backend Node.js. I'm using AWS Cognito to authenticate on the frontend, however, I need to know if the user is authenticated in my Node.js backend to allow some routes.

Right now I have two solutions in mind:

- Send the JWT Token from the front to the back at each route call to see if the user is properly logged in. But I don't know how it's going to affect my backend performances nor if it's a good practice, and if there's a secure way to do this
- In Node.js (I am also using express), check from which web server the route is called from. If it's from my domain, it's mean I can allow the route

What should be the way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Send either the Cognito id or access token along with each request and decode it yourself. The tokens are signed. AWS provides a mechanism for you to download the signing keys for your user pool. You would have the overhead of running RSA to verify the tokens, but the cost should be negligible.

There are a bunch of resources on how to decode the tokens yourself:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt